# Localize additional strings in C# Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization

I have a control which is localized. I'm using the VS Net designer and end up with MyControl.cs, MyControl.Designer.cs, MyControl.resx and some MyControl.xx.resx for the non-default languages.

Some of the strings that are displayed are dynamic and I need to call string.Format on them (eg I have "Hello, would you like to {0} today?", and I could format it using "read a book" or "watch TV"). How should I handle those dynamic strings?

For now I added the string to format in a label in the designer, but I don't know where to put the replacement strings. I could create an independent resx file just for them, but it feels like a mess just for a few strings. I could also have an independent resx file for all such strings throughout my application, but then it's like a potpourri and it sounds messy too.

The cleanest way would be to simply add those strings to the existing MyControl.resx and MyControl.xx.resx, but I dont know:

- if it's safe (ie whether the VS Net designer will mess with them, just like I shouldn't manually modify the InitializeComponent method)
- how to access those strings (in InitializeComponent I see how it's being used for a control `resources.ApplyResources(this.myLabel, "myLabel")`, but can I have a string which is not related to a control, and could I avoid using magic strings?)

Comment: Keep in mind, you may want to opt to localize entire phrases instead of substituting localized replacement strings in a localized format.  Some languages are structured different enough from English that this current approach could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx). The link also has an example for your case